# How to configure my RDS postgresql instance so that i can interact with my API server EC2 ubuntu machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am able to access my RDS instance through my EC2 instance through

```
 psql -U user -h hostname  $DBname
```

I want to know how the RDS connects to EC2. is it private IP or public IP or Hostname

my developer has configured my private IP in connection  http://privateip:5000 in the backend (don't what exactly it)

When I use this command:

```
 curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Supplier
```

I am able to access the API response.

but when I use my

```
 curl --location --request GET 'http://privateip:5000/api/Supplier
```

I get curl: (7) Failed to connect to privateIp port 5000: Connection refused

I am sure my EC2 can connect to RDS .

Maybe my understanding of this is limited.

could any one help me out of this ?

My RDS SG

```
All TCP TCP 0 - 65535 Custom sg-EC2

PostgreSQL TCP 5432 Custom 0.0.0.0/0

PostgreSQL TCP 5432 custom sg-Ec2

All UDP UDP 0 - 65535 Custom sg-EC2

All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP 0 - 65535 Custom sg-EC2
```

Comment: @Chris Williams

Comment: So this is calling a get request on your private ip on port 5000, can you confirm the security groups on the instance that you're trying to connect to?

Comment: All TCP
TCP
0 - 65535

Custom
sg-ec2 instance 

PostgreSQL
TCP
5432

Custom
0.0.0.0/0


PostgreSQL
TCP
5432

Custom
sg-ec2 instance 

All UDP
UDP
0 - 65535

Custom
sg-ec2 instance 


All ICMP - IPv4
ICMP
0 - 65535

Custom
sg-ec2 instance

Comment: Could you add formatted to question? :)

Comment: The request you fired is a curl request which is targetted to your EC2 instance not your RDS, does your EC2 instance also run the same security group

Comment: @ChrisWilliams   no, it runs on different SG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216761/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-sumanth-shetty).

Answer (score 1):

**Rule of thumb** for checking SG of instance `telnet privateip 5000` if the port is not open it clearly indicate that EC2 instance security group not allowing the port.

Then open `5000` from SG of the instance.

If the above fix does not resolve the issue then it might be the case that application only listening on `localhost` so you need to allow `0.0.0.0` to work it private IP.

> I am sure my EC2 can connect to RDS .

The issue is related to connecting with Ec2 instance not the RDS,  you request `curl --location --request GET 'http://privateip:5000/api/Supplier` has nothing to do with RDS except DB connection. you application depend on Ec2 security group, not the RDS security group.

Comment: I have an inbound rule for my ec2 

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
5000

Custom
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Okay which application is running? Are you sure it's not Bind with localhost?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to connect to the private IP address from the instance itself you will need to ensure the following conditions are met:

- Inbound access in the security group from the source of your instance to port 5000.
- Outbound access allowed in the security group for your instance.
- NACL is either the default NACL, or if you have made your own it is allowing inbound and outbound access including to [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html).

The source inbound rule for the security group should be scoped to one of the following:

- Inbound from the private IP address range of the EC2 instance e.g. `10.0.0.1/32`
- Inbound from either a subnet or VPC range e.g. `10.0.0.0/16`.
- Inbound from the world e.g. `0.0.0.0/0` (Use with caution as this allows any server that can connect, to be able to connect on this port).
- Inbound from a security group (either the same or different). e.g. `sd-abcdef`

Comment: the private ip which i am using is of the EC2 machine not of the RDS. is what is m doing right?

Comment: The EC2 instance will be running the curl request against itself, so yes the private IP should be the EC2s

Comment: What if the instance which is trying to access the RDS is in other subnet?

Comment: As long as the security group allows you should be fine :)

Comment: can we have two Postgres RDS each in separate AZ be in sync.
Or should we go for Multi Az Deployment from one AZ only?

Comment: If you're looking to have this for HA then yes use multi AZ, if its performance then it would need to be a read replica as you cannot use the standby node in a multi AZ setup

Comment: hope i got this right,
Best Practices would be to have a single RDS with multi az deployment compared to two different RDS for each AZ?

Comment: Always a lifesaver, but still not able to find you on linked in.

Comment: Could you help me out with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671161/unit-xxx-service-is-not-loaded-properly-exec-format-error-on-ubuntu18-04-creat